# Subdomain with SSL certificates can't be reached

Tags: nginx, asp.net-core, ssl-certificate, wildcard-subdomain, godaddy-api

I have an asp net core application running in a Linux server on a Google Cloud engine. The home page is displayed perfectly, but when I click a button to navigate to a subdomain I get "This site can’t be reached" with "ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED". I don't see any errors in the application log so I suppose the call can't even reach the application.

When the application is running on a local Windows machine all the subdomains are able to reach and completely working.

I've tried running the application in an local Linux machine and the results are the same. Everything is working fine.

On the server subdomain are only able to reach when there is no SSL certificate requested for.

For example when I create a subdomain: subdomain.example.com am I able to reach it. With this working I requested a certificate for the current subdomain. This is working aswell and the subdomain is currently secured. But when I create a new subdomain and repeat the previous steps the earlier subdomain isn't working anymore but the new subdomain is.

Beside all this subdomains are working perfectly when no certificate is requested but then are the subdomains "unsecured".

The certificates are requested using GoDaddy.

This is the Nginx configuration:

```
server {
    server_name   example.com *.example.com;
    location / {
        proxy_pass         https://localhost:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection keep-alive;
        proxy_set_header   Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    }

    location /activityhub {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /votehub {
        proxy_pass https://localhost:5001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;

    }

    listen 443 ssl; 
    ssl_certificate /root/letsencrypt/dehydrated/certs/example.com/fullchain.pem; 
    ssl_certificate_key /root/letsencrypt/dehydrated/certs/example.com/privkey.pem;
}

server {
    if ($host = example.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } 
}
```

The idea is a site where users can create different subdomains for their organisations. So when a user presses a button they can create a subdomain: organisation.example.com to display their own organisation. The application creates at this moment a subdomain on https://organisation.localhost:5001. Now this should automatically be display secured on the website with dns like "https://organisation.example.com. The domains requested for the SSL certificate are example.com and *.example.com

I expect to get all the subdomains working with SSL certificate without subdomains being unsecure or unreachable. All those subdomains should be working with wildcards.

Comment: you can try `sudo nginx -t` to check if your config file is valid

Comment: @Kai config file is valid:
nginx: the configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: configuration file /etc/nginx/nginx.conf test is successful

Comment: is that all your nginx config files or just the new one you that you created by "repeat the previous step" ?

Comment: This the only nginx config file. The only thing I did was creating a new subdomain within the application itself.

Comment: may I know that did you create the 1st subdomain on domain manager panel, or just config nginx?

Comment: The first 2 subdomains are seeded with the application. So when I start the web app I have a subdomain subdomain1.example.com and subdomain2.example.com. Both those subdomains don't work when I request SSL certificates for them. A new subdomain is created within the application and not in Nginx.

Comment: sorry but I cannot get you... and, the config in your files there is no configuration for subdomain. And, can you check your SSL certificate support wildcard or not?

Comment: The idea is a site where users can create different subdomains for their organisations. So when a user presses a button they can create a subdomain: organisation.example.com to display their own organisation. The application creates at this moment a subdomain on https://organisation.localhost:5001. Now this should automatically be display  secured on the website with dns like "https://organisation.example.com but the problem is that the page is unreachable and it even cannot reach my application. The domains requested for the SSL certificate are example.com and *.example.com.